# How to use refresh token in Nuxt auth module (oauth2) with keycloak when access token expired

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, keycloak, keycloak-services

Access token(Bearer JWT token) is working success after login, but after 1-2 minutes access token expired, and axios request return 401 unauthorized, and nuxt app have a refresh token, but how use it in nuxt correctly to update access token from keycloak service.  Here is my nuxt.config.js

```
    strategies: {
      keycloak: {
        _scheme: 'oauth2',
        authorization_endpoint: `${process.env.AUTH_URL}/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/auth`,
        access_token_endpoint: `${process.env.AUTH_URL}/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/token`,
        scope: [
          'openid',
          'address',
          'email',
          'jhipster',
          'microprofile-jwt',
          'offline_access',
          'phone',
          'profile',
          'roles',
          'web-origins'
        ],
        response_type: 'code',
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        token_type: 'Bearer',
        client_id: 'web_app',
        token_key: 'access_token',
        autoLogout: true
      }
    }
```

Here is my keycloak config in admin UI
[image]

Comment: Have you had create a nuxtServerInit function to inject your token as cookie?

Comment: access token and refresh token saved in localstorage as default by nuxt after login, i have not create a nuxtServerInit function, and why i should store token as cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

We have faced the very same issue this past week, with v4.9.1.

After digging into the source code, it became apparent that while the upcoming v5 of this module may introduce support for automatic refreshing of access tokens using refresh tokens, v4 it seems does not, despite storing the refresh token.

In order to work around this until v5 has a stable release, we created a [module plugin](https://gist.github.com/rwd/3dc19afb11f4ad2fbffaf94a6c9a88bf). Add that to your project directory, and supply to [Nuxt Auth plugins](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options.html#plugins).

The accompanying strategy configuration in nuxt.config.js uses:

```
...
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  response_type: 'code',
  access_type: 'online'
...
```

(Of which `grant_type` was not obvious as is not [documented](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/oauth2.html).)

In addition, in the configuration of the client in Keycloak itself, we had to:

- Disable `implicit flow`
- Set `access type` to "public"
- Set `web origins` to permit CORS requests from your Nuxt app's deployment URLs, or to `+` if these are already configured as "Valid Redirect URIs"

This works well for us, catching 401s from Keycloak when access tokens have expired, using the refresh token to gain a new access token, and then retrying the original failed request.

(Cross-posted from my answer to [an issue reporting the same on the Nuxt Auth repo](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/864#issuecomment-725536901).)